# Android LocationServices lastKnownPosition

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location, google-api-client

I've looked around but couldn't find a solution. I'm trying to find the last known position in Android, and I've seen this from google developer, but the function `onConnected()` is never called. Also, if I put this in `onCreate()`, the geolocalisation icon of Android is never turned on.

The app uses the permissions and google services which already uses FusedLocation.

```
//class implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    [...]
    buildGoogleApiClient();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        String lat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()); //it's only for test
        String lng = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Never mind, after one day off the funcion is working fine. The code is the same. Shall I delete the question?

Answer (score 0):

You should use FusedLocationProvide api ,It provide location update while you are in building with more accuracy.Below is code -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  //put your code here
  ....
  getLocation();
}

private void getLocation(){
   locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
   locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
   locationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
   locationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_INTERVAL);
   fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
   googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
   .addApi(LocationServices.API)
   .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
   .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
   .build();
   if (googleApiClient != null) {
      googleApiClient.connect();
   }
}  


 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
     fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,   locationRequest, this);
  }

 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "location :"+location.getLatitude()+" , "+location.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

it will sure work.Lets try it.